# What are possible theories/models to describe social influence based on frequency?

Tags: probability-theory

I am working on social influence based on frequency, meaning if a person repeatedly appears at a location many times then he/she is more influential at that location. In other words, he/she can influence other people at that location with a higher chance of success compared to someone who is not there often.

For example, if a professor at a university has worked there over many years, therefore he has been seen at the school many times, thus he should be influential at that school.

I have been looking for a mathematical/statistic model that can, or at least, can partially describe the influence quantitatively based on the frequency of visiting a particular location. So my questions are:

1) Do you have any suggestions of what in math/stats that may be related to this? I am just asking for your opinions/suggestions in general, which do not have to be correct, but can still be immensely helpful. Note that I assume friendships have already be considered in this social influence problem. Here, I just pay attention to frequency of visits. The frequency may be related to social status, social power, which in turn can affect social influence.

2) Regardless of question 1, do you think the assumption "the higher the frequency, the more influential" is intuitively correct?

Any response/agreement/disagreement/opinions would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a shot for what it's worth.  It seems like you are looking for a model where each time someone appears at a place they get more credibility points at that place.  This raises the question of how should these credibility points be assigned.  We could assign $1$ point per appearance.  But perhaps there should be some diminishing returns, so perhaps after $n$ appearances someone has $\sqrt{n}$ credibility points.  Or maybe there should be some asymptotic limit to the number of credibility points that can be accumulated.

Also as I think about people I know, some lose credibility when they appear (or say things).  Sometimes I lose MSE credibility points when I say things :-).

I don't know if in 2) "the higher the frequency, the more influential" is always correct.  Here are three quotes to think about in that regard: "Familiarity breeds contempt" (from an Aesop Fable); "An expert is someone from out of town" (Mark Twain?); "A prophet is honored everywhere except in his own hometown." (Bible, Mark 6:4).

Comment: excellent shot! Thanks for giving it such a thorough thought and a well-written explanation. Your assumption is right: "each time someone appears at a place they get more credibility points at that place". This is definitely a motivation for me to think ahead!

Comment: I like that you mention the "diminishing return" property. Good point!